# What's the difference between onReceivedClientCertRequest and onReceivedLSslError

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-webview

Since both have to handle a certificate, isn't it the same? What are some different scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onReceivedSslError` is called when there is an error in the SSL certificate of the server.  For example, it might be a self-signed certificate, it could be for the wrong domain, it may have expired, etc.

`onReceivedClientCertRequest` is called when the server requests that the client device send a certificate for authentication purposes.  An example of a website that uses SSL certificates for client authentication is [StartSSL](https://startssl.com).

Answer (score 2):

`onReceivedSslError` and `onReceivedClientCertRequest` are different.

**onReceivedSslError**

Notify the host application that an SSL error occurred while loading a resource.

**onReceivedClientCertRequest**

Notify the host application to handle a SSL client certificate request.

Comment: I still dont get it. When a SSL error occured means that the client has to handle some certificate, right? If the client has the certificate then can establish a secure connection. I can't find what the ClientCertRequest does. I'm not so into this stuff.